# Lookahead and Lookbehind not working in Spark SQL

Tags: regex, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a string that starts with 2 digit number (0-9) followed by a  period "." which followed by any character any number of times and then a front slash ("/") then followed by any character (including front slash).  I want to be able to see if a set of special characters [;:@&=+$,] is present in the text after the first front slash one or more times and extract the same.

However lookbehind is not working in Spark SQL. What could be wrong ?

From the docs looks like Spark uses the Java flavour of regex.

> E.g. 20.3426999/1234567arw#1:2

```
select regexp_extract(t.mystring, (?<=[0-9]\..*/).*[;:@&=+$,]+) as special_char_pattern
from mytable t
```

Acceptable Output:

> [#, :]

Or at least

> 1234567arw#1:2

Answer (score 0):

If it is Java, you could make use of a finite quantifier in the lookbehind assertion, and then make sure to match one of the listed characters in the character class. In the quantifier `{0,100}` the 100 is just an arbitrary number which you can change.

```
(?<=[0-9][0-9]\.[^/\n]{0,100}/)[^;:@&=+$,\n]*[;:@&=+$,].*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/v87AJ1/1)

The other option could be making use of a capture group instead of a lookbehind assertion:

```
[0-9][0-9]\.[^/\n]{0,100}/([^;:@&=+$,\n]*[;:@&=+$,].*)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rx2yBu/1)

**Note** that you can not have `[#, :]` as output as the character class that you use for matching only contains the `:` and there is no comma in the example data.

If you want to match only the colon, then [you might use](https://regex101.com/r/FlqGS9/1):

```
(?<=[0-9][0-9]\.[^/\n]{0,100}/[^;:@&=+$,\n]{0,100})[;:@&=+$,]]
```